# .elasticX(true) doesn't work dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I have a Composite Linechart

The  .elasticX(true) does not work :/ Could Someone help me

```
var composite = dc.compositeChart("#durationline-chart");
    composite.width(1500).height(350)
        .group(Durations)
        .brushOn(true)
        .yAxisLabel("Duration")
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .margins({ top: 10, left: 50, right: 10, bottom: 50 })
        .elasticY(true)
        .elasticX(true)
        .renderlet(function(chart) {
                chart.selectAll("g.x text")
                    .attr('transform', "rotate(+20)");
            })
        .compose([
            dc.lineChart(composite)
                .group(Testcase_Time, "Time")
                .colors('#1E90FF'),
            dc.lineChart(composite)
                .group(Testcase_Smartkey, "Smartkey")
                .colors('red')]);
```

EDIT: Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/o9xx3fmm/

Comment: Please provide more information about the error. Any messages? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have an other Chart (Rowchart) and if im clicking on it, i only see the clicked testcase on the line chart thats cool but the xaxis is to big it would be cool if the axis will be dynamic like the Y axis... Do you know what i mean

Comment: i dont have a error... But nothing happens on the X axis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean the elastic is not kicking in when the chart is filtered.

This is because crossfilter still returns bins if they are empty - they just have value zero. So dc.js still detects the domain of all the bins, including the empty ones.

What you can do is use a fake group to remove the empty bins

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value != 0;
            });
        }
    };
}


var filtered_group = remove_empty_bins(group);

chart.dimension(dim)
    .group(filtered_group)
    ...
```

Then dc.js will detect only the domain of non zero values. More details [in the FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#remove-empty-bins).

You have to apply this to all groups that make up the chart.

Comment: i tried this before... but it didint work. The Xaxis works but i cant see any lines

Comment: Okay, it would have helped if you had mentioned that. Can you create a fiddle showing the problem with this approach? It may be a bug or we may need to use a further workaround [like this one](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#combine-groups), which is for stacks not composites.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to filter all of the groups, which is super annoying but it seems to work for me. The only problem I see is that there is only one data point per series, so there are no lines to draw unless the zeros are included. When I add another data point for each series, I get charts. (There are some annoying transitions due to bugs in dc.js, which should be resolved when 2.0 is finally released.)

Comment: Here's my fork of your fiddle with the fixes: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/o9xx3fmm/4/

Comment: Hey Gordon everything worked.. but i added some more Testcases know i get the Exception: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined

Comment: Again, @oz2311, I'm not sure what you're referring to without seeing your code. It's there a problem in the code I supplied or in your test cases?

Comment: Hey Gordon Is there a chance to dont ask in the line chart this if (d.TestCase === 'Coldstart') ... Because i integrated my crossfilter code to a c# code witch gives the data in a database(with php) and then i'm getting the data from the database(also with php) then im goging to use them in my crossfilter.. Everything works but if i'm starting an other Test(It's a testing Project) in my c# code which haves other Testcases then my Line chart is 
naturally not working.. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: You mean, to refactor it so that you can generate as many of those filtered-value-fetchers as you need? Yep, this is probably a better design anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/o9xx3fmm/6/